# Парсинг XML в цикле foreach c#

Tags: c#, xml

Пытаюсь перебрать значения из элементов XML. Нашел в интернете пример. Но в моем случае получается бесконечный цикл. Не могу понять почему.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Streamers>
  <Streamer>
    <Name>WELOVEGAMES</Name>
    <Status>rerun</Status>
  </Streamer>
  <Streamer>
    <Name>aihhho</Name>
    <Status>live</Status>
  </Streamer>
</Streamers>
```

Сам цикл

```
List<string> streamersName = new List<string>(); 
foreach (XElement phoneElement in xDoc.Element("Streamers").Elements("Streamer"))
{ 
    XElement Element = phoneElement.Element("Name");
    streamersName.Add(Element.Value);
}
```

Ошибка.- "Полный текст сообщения: вычисление функции «функция» истекло время ожидания и требуется завершить небезопасным образом. Это возможно повреждение в целевом процессе."

Инициализация xDoc

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path + @"/Data/StreamersList.xml");
```

Comment: С кодом который вы скинули, это никак не связано. Единственное только выложите инициализацию xDoc!

Comment: Yury Bakharev, в цикле for все нормально парсится если сделать Streamer1, Streamer2

Comment: `xDoc.Element("Streamers").Elements("Streamer")` => `xDoc.Root.Elements("Streamer")`

Comment: При чем тут цикл "for"  я не знаю, а так у вас и так все должно "парситься"! Ничего что может уйти в бесконечный цикл, в коде нет.

Comment: @rdorn это из за студии?

Comment: В приведенном фрагменте кода бесконечного цикла нет. Ищите в другом месте.

Comment: @rdorn Я за тебя голосовал!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85672/discussion-between-yury-bakharev-and-rdorn).

Comment: Как вариант - проверьте что файл не "битый" и имеет корректное форматирование (теги не потеряны, недопустимых символов нет), хотя в случае нарушения формата должен упасть еще на `XDocument.Load`

Comment: Такая ошибка обычно в студии вываливается, если пухлые переменные смотреть.